# How to mark particular records or ranges as deleted in Timestream

Tags: data-modeling, amazon-timestream

I have a stream processing application that constantly ingest the data to AWS Timestream.

I try to come up with the approach when a particular range of data is processed incorrectly, thus I need to re-ingest them again and mark the ones that are already processed as deleted.

What is the best approach to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Version field while re-ingesting data.

When Version field is provided Timestream overwrites/upserts the data if it has higher Version.

Ref: [Timestream Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/code-samples.write.html#code-samples.write.upserts)